# Sencha CMD YUICompressor [ERR] Failed to compress input

Tags: java, extjs, ant, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd

While building a sencha touch project I am facing error `[ERR] Failed to compress input`. So I recompiled it with `-d` (debug) flag and the output is following.

```
[DBG] Load url is file:/opt/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.2.342/lib/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
[ERR] Failed to compress input
     at com.sencha.tools.compressors.yui.YuiJavascriptCompressor.runYuiCompressor(YuiJavascriptCompressor.java:149)
     at com.sencha.tools.compressors.yui.YuiJavascriptCompressor.compress(YuiJavascriptCompressor.java:160)
     at com.sencha.tools.compressors.yui.YuiJavascriptCompressor.compress(YuiJavascriptCompressor.java:170)
     at com.sencha.tools.compiler.jsb.projects.Project.compressTarget(Project.java:130)
     at com.sencha.tools.compiler.jsb.projects.Target.afterCreate(Target.java:135)
     at com.sencha.tools.compiler.jsb.projects.Build.afterCreate(Build.java:103)
     at com.sencha.tools.compiler.jsb.projects.Target.create(Target.java:79)
     at com.sencha.tools.compiler.jsb.projects.Project.createBuilds(Project.java:103)
     at com.sencha.tools.compiler.jsb.projects.Project.build(Project.java:89)
     at com.sencha.tools.compiler.jsb.projects.JsbBuilder.processBuild(JsbBuilder.java:57)
     at com.sencha.command.build.JsbCommand.execute(JsbCommand.java:15)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
     at com.sencha.util.MethodInvoker$Arguments.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:174)
     at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:42)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:62)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:78)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:141)
   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at com.sencha.util.ReflectionUtil.newInstance(ReflectionUtil.java:120)
     at com.sencha.tools.compressors.yui.YuiJavascriptCompressor.runYuiCompressor(YuiJavascriptCompressor.java:114)
     at com.sencha.tools.compressors.yui.YuiJavascriptCompressor.compress(YuiJavascriptCompressor.java:160)
     at com.sencha.tools.compressors.yui.YuiJavascriptCompressor.compress(YuiJavascriptCompressor.java:170)
     at com.sencha.tools.compiler.jsb.projects.Project.compressTarget(Project.java:130)
     at com.sencha.tools.compiler.jsb.projects.Target.afterCreate(Target.java:135)
     at com.sencha.tools.compiler.jsb.projects.Build.afterCreate(Build.java:103)
     at com.sencha.tools.compiler.jsb.projects.Target.create(Target.java:79)
     at com.sencha.tools.compiler.jsb.projects.Project.createBuilds(Project.java:103)
     at com.sencha.tools.compiler.jsb.projects.Project.build(Project.java:89)
     at com.sencha.tools.compiler.jsb.projects.JsbBuilder.processBuild(JsbBuilder.java:57)
     at com.sencha.command.build.JsbCommand.execute(JsbCommand.java:15)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
     at com.sencha.util.MethodInvoker$Arguments.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:174)
     at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:42)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:62)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:78)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:141)
   Caused by: null
     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
     at com.sencha.util.ReflectionUtil.newInstance(ReflectionUtil.java:116)
     at com.sencha.tools.compressors.yui.YuiJavascriptCompressor.runYuiCompressor(YuiJavascriptCompressor.java:114)
     at com.sencha.tools.compressors.yui.YuiJavascriptCompressor.compress(YuiJavascriptCompressor.java:160)
     at com.sencha.tools.compressors.yui.YuiJavascriptCompressor.compress(YuiJavascriptCompressor.java:170)
     at com.sencha.tools.compiler.jsb.projects.Project.compressTarget(Project.java:130)
     at com.sencha.tools.compiler.jsb.projects.Target.afterCreate(Target.java:135)
     at com.sencha.tools.compiler.jsb.projects.Build.afterCreate(Build.java:103)
     at com.sencha.tools.compiler.jsb.projects.Target.create(Target.java:79)
     at com.sencha.tools.compiler.jsb.projects.Project.createBuilds(Project.java:103)
     at com.sencha.tools.compiler.jsb.projects.Project.build(Project.java:89)
     at com.sencha.tools.compiler.jsb.projects.JsbBuilder.processBuild(JsbBuilder.java:57)
     at com.sencha.command.build.JsbCommand.execute(JsbCommand.java:15)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
     at com.sencha.util.MethodInvoker$Arguments.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:174)
     at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:42)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:62)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:78)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:141)
   Caused by: null
     at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.printSourceNumber(JavaScriptCompressor.java:299)
     at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.parse(JavaScriptCompressor.java:336)
     at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.<init>(JavaScriptCompressor.java:533)
     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
     at com.sencha.util.ReflectionUtil.newInstance(ReflectionUtil.java:116)
     at com.sencha.tools.compressors.yui.YuiJavascriptCompressor.runYuiCompressor(YuiJavascriptCompressor.java:114)
     at com.sencha.tools.compressors.yui.YuiJavascriptCompressor.compress(YuiJavascriptCompressor.java:160)
     at com.sencha.tools.compressors.yui.YuiJavascriptCompressor.compress(YuiJavascriptCompressor.java:170)
     at com.sencha.tools.compiler.jsb.projects.Project.compressTarget(Project.java:130)
     at com.sencha.tools.compiler.jsb.projects.Target.afterCreate(Target.java:135)
     at com.sencha.tools.compiler.jsb.projects.Build.afterCreate(Build.java:103)
     at com.sencha.tools.compiler.jsb.projects.Target.create(Target.java:79)
     at com.sencha.tools.compiler.jsb.projects.Project.createBuilds(Project.java:103)
     at com.sencha.tools.compiler.jsb.projects.Project.build(Project.java:89)
     at com.sencha.tools.compiler.jsb.projects.JsbBuilder.processBuild(JsbBuilder.java:57)
     at com.sencha.command.build.JsbCommand.execute(JsbCommand.java:15)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
     at com.sencha.util.MethodInvoker$Arguments.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:174)
     at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:42)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:62)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:78)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:141)
```

This same code builds on every other machine. I am using `Sencha Cmd v3.1.2.342`. 
Tested in following config.

- Machine 1

  - Sencha CMD 3.1.2.342
  - Java 1.6
  - 32 bit Fedora 12
  - Build **Fails**
- Machine 2

  - Sencha CMD 3.1.2.342
  - Java 1.6
  - 32 bit Fedora 15
  - Build **Passes**
- Machine 3

  - Sencha CMD 3.0.0
  - Java 1.6
  - 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04
  - Build **Passes**

I am using Sencha CMD to build using a `.jsb3` file only.

What could be the reason for failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is fixed. Here's what I did.

1. Reinstall or `ant` and `java`. Note instead of Sun Java, I used OpenJDK from the beginning. So installing Sun Java might be a good option.
2. Update the whole machine to latest packages. (for Fedora its `yum update` and for Ubuntu its `apt-get upgrade`)